# Javascript Not Updating Function on Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I've got a script that looks to see how many records are "unread" for notifications.  When I use the following code the page will load then number when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
});
```

But I'm trying to make it update every 5 secs so I searched around and found this but it's not working.  I'm trying to figure out how to get it operational.  Here is the Javascript code:

```
//TRYING TO GET TO UPDATE EVERY 5 SECONDS
window.setInterval(function(){
function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
}
}, 5000);




//THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS WHEN A PARTICULAR BUTTON IS PRESSED
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).show();
//GET THE NOTIFICATIONS
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?page=<? echo $page; ?>");
});

//RESET THE NUMBER OF NOTIFICATIONS UNREAD
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
});


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was putting the code to do inside 2 functions.  The code should be:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra function declaration in here - it won't ever execute:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you shouldn't use `setInterval` like that. The response order isn't guaranteed, you should use `setTimeout` inside the callback to guarantee you get a response before sending the next request off:

```
function getNotes() {
    $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php", function() {
        setTimeout(getNotes, 5000);
    });
}

getNotes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace following chunk of code

```
window.setInterval(function(){
function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
}
}, 5000);
```

with

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");
}, 5000);
```